# How to restore Mongo(WT engine) only with collection-0-****.wt file?

Tags: mongodb

My mongodb can't lanuch now, when I want start mongo got error `***aborting after invariant() failure`

Now I want to restore collection-0-****.wt file to a new db, is this possible?

Comment: FYI, questions on database administration belong on DBA StackExchange rather than StackOverflow. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Hopefully a moderator should migrate this so there is no need to repost.

Answer (score 1):

As at MongoDB 3.2, only full backups of WiredTiger data directories can be copied into a new instance. WiredTiger collection or index files aren't self-contained; they rely on other metadata in the `WiredTiger.*` catalog files. The invariant/assertion you are getting on startup is expected if data files are incomplete or inconsistent.

If you want to backup and restore a single collection, you should use `mongodump` and `mongorestore`, eg:

```
 mongodump --db test --collection northwind --host host1

 mongorestore --db test dump/test/northwind.bson --host host2
```

For supported full backup procedures, see: [MongoDB Backup Methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/).

Comment: Hi, @Stennie, we've keep whole dbpath folder,but we can't lanuch mongo now. Can I build the `WiredTiger.*` catalog files by myself?

Comment: @diggzhang Is your original `mongod` instance still running? If you have access to a working instance I'd follow one of the supported backup & restore procedures. If you don't ... as a last resort you could try `mongod --repair`. I think restoring with the full dbpath is a different question (and one that probably involves more discussion than is suitable on StackOverflow). I'd suggest posting a new question with more details on either [DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/mongodb) or the [mongodb-user discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mongodb-user).

Comment: @ Stennie, Yeah I was use `mongod --reqair` but still got the trace error.

Comment: hello, my windows 10 computer blue screened and after doing a system reset i only have directory files available (eg `.wt` files) - is it possible to restore from them? I have posted all details [in a question here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/216759/how-to-restore-from-wt-files). thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after spending 5 hours doing everything, found this.
https://medium.com/@imunscarred/repairing-mongodb-when-wiredtiger-wt-file-is-corrupted-9405978751b5

You will need to restore 1 collection at a time(a few at once when you get the hang of it), but it works!